# Open Google Map in new window on click

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have embedded a Google map in my web page. Now I want to open that same map in a new pop-up window. Can any one let me know how to do it?

I tried few option which I got through google search and from SF but they are not working. In one of the forum it was mentioned that wrap the div which has the map with  tag but what URL has to be passed to it?

`@Update`

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
var amsterdam=new google.maps.LatLng(18.5204303,73.85624369999992);
var lat;
var long;

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:amsterdam,
  zoom:8,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var reslatlon = null;
var location = "pune,maharashtra";

if(!geocoder) {
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

var geocoderRequest = {
   address: location
}
var myCity = null;
geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {
//alert(status);
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    reslatlon = results[0].geometry.location;
lat = results[0].geometry.location.hb;
long = results[0].geometry.location.ib;
amsterdam = new     google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.hb,results[0].geometry.location.ib);
//alert(results[0].geometry.location.hb + " , " + results[0].geometry.location.ib);
myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
center:amsterdam,
radius:25000,
strokeColor:"#0000ff",
strokeOpacity:0.8,
strokeWeight:2,
fillColor:"#0000ff",
fillOpacity:0.4,
map:map
});

 }
});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function openWin(){
alert(lat + " , " + long);
window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?    ll="+lat+","+long,'MYMAP','height=400,width=600');return true;

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a target="MYMAP" onclick="openWin()" href="">
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly you have tried and what did not work?

Comment: The code is working now. I was trying it in w3schools Try it window. there it was opening the pop-up window but it was blank.

Now the problem is when ever I click the map in the pop-up window it again reloads as the click event is also transferred to the pop-up window. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: please create a fiddle based on your current implementation

Comment: I am not sure how to use fiddle I have added my code in my question above.